# Read contents of a pdf file

Tags: python, linux, pdf, shell, command-line

Is there a commandline tool to read a pdf file on linux.Please indicate the appropriate urls for this.

Thanks..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Xpdf](http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/) and [Poppler](http://poppler.freedesktop.org/) contain the commandline-utility `pdftotext` wich converts PDF files to plain text.

Answer (score 0):

Not a command line tool but a pdf reading and generation framework

- http://www.reportlab.com/software/opensource/

you should also be able to write a simple reader using

- https://pypi.org/project/pypdf/
- http://code.activestate.com/recipes/511465-pure-python-pdf-to-text-converter/

you can also look at:

- [http://www.unixuser.org/~euske/python/pdfminer/index.html](http://www.unixuser.org/%7Eeuske/python/pdfminer/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

There is [PyODConverter](http://www.artofsolving.com/opensource/pyodconverter). It uses OpenOffice working as a service and can convert between various document formats including PDF and simple text.

Comment: On the project WWW pages there are examples of usage from command line. I use this library in Web application to "standarize" various formats to PDF and text (text is further used to full text search).

Comment: Niklas:My requirement is kind of similar.Couldnt get it work as of now from the example pages.Examples and help appreciated

Comment: It is hard to say what is not working in your environment. No OpenOffice service? No Python/UNO bridge? I suggest asking new question (on SO or JODConverter Group) or adding more info. There is more info of Java conversion tool/library: http://www.artofsolving.com/opensource/jodconverter/guide (read about starting OOo as service).